# Rails single table inheritance validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, single-table-inheritance

There is a `Request` model in my app. On different pages I need different validations, for example on `/contacts` I need to validate a lot of fields, whereas in a 'call me back later' popup I need to validate only phone number and name.

My problem is: data is saved, but without validations and `type` is not saved aswell.

Structure:
`request.rb`

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord

  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

  def self.types
      %w(ContactRequest CallMeBackRequest)
  end

  scope :contacts, -> { where(type: 'ContactRequest') } 
  scope :callmebacks, -> { where(type: 'CallMeBackRequest') } 
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :contact_requests, only: [:new, :create], controller: 'requests', type: 'ContactRequest'
resources :call_me_back_requests, only: [:new, :create], controller: 'requests', type: 'CallMeBackRequest'
```

contact_request.rb:

```
class ContactRequest < Request
  validates :name, :phone, :email, :company_name, presence: true

  def self.sti_name
    "ContactRequest"
  end
end
```

call_me_back_request.rb:

```
class CallMeBackRequest < Request
  validates :name, :phone, presence: true

  def self.sti_name
    "CallMeBack"
  end
end
```

requests_controller.rb:

```
class Front::RequestsController < FrontController
  before_action :set_type

  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js { render partial: 'fail' }

      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_request
    @request = type_class.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_type
     @type = type
  end

  def type
      Request.types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : "Request"
  end

  def type_class 
      type.constantize 
  end

  def request_params
    params.require(type.underscore.to_sym).permit(Request.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
  end
end
```

My form starts with:

```
=form_for Request.contacts.new, format: 'js', html: {class: 'g-contact__sidebar-right g-form'}, remote: true do |f|
```

I tried using `ContactRequest.new` - result was the same.

What I get when I hit the console:

- `Request.contacts.create!(name: "something")` - does get saved, no validations are applied (why?). No `type` field is populated - why?
- `ContactRequest.create!(name: "something")` - does not get saved, validations are applied
- `ContactRequest.create!(name: ..., all other required fields)` - does get saved, but field `type` is empty - why?

Whatever I use for my form - `ContactRequest.new` or `Request.contacts.new` - neither validations are applied nor field `type` is set correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm mainly using [this tutorial](https://devblast.com/b/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-3/) and other SO question, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - since I'm not using the dedicated pages and paths for those contacts, i.e. `contact_requests_path` and corresponding `new.html.haml`, I need to pass the `type` parameter as a hidden field.

So my form now looks like this:

```
=form_for ContactRequest.new, format: 'js', html: {class: 'g-contact__sidebar-right g-form'}, remote: true do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :type, value: "ContactRequest"
```

Considering validations - I don't know what I did, but after restarting the server a few times, they work now. The only this I remember really changing was the sti name here:

```
class CallMeBackRequest < Request
  validates :name, :phone, presence: true

  def self.sti_name
    "CallMeBack" <- changed it from "CallMeBack" to "CallMeBackRequest"
  end
end
```